# Bottom space is not affecting with UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added section insets top:20, left:10, right:10 and bottom:10 in collection view. Everything is fine there but bottom space is not affecting there as a result cells are overlapping from bottom one another.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: what is height of cell ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20,10,10,10);
}
```

Comment: I have added the above code but it doesn't work, it seems that I have added those already using xcode size interface though doesn't work. Don't know why.

Comment: Maybe you do not specify a delegate and a datasource for your collectionview

self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[yourCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCell];
    self.collectionViewLayout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;

Comment: In viewDidLoad method in your class